# defaults using Getdate and DateAdd are not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I set up a table yesterday with the following code. the code ran with no error messages reported and the table appeared correctly set up in object explorer.

```
Create Table PriceTable
             (Airport_IACO_Code Varchar (4) NOT NULL,
              Airline_IACO_Code Varchar (3) NOT NULL,
              FlightDate Date NOT NULL Default Getdate(),
              DepTime Time NOT NULL Default DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE()),
              Price Smallmoney,
              RouteDiscontinuedOrCommences Varchar (15),
              )
GO
```

However on checking the table today the `FlightDate` which has the `Getdate()` default is showing yesterdays date

and

the the DepTime column which has the `DateAdd` Default is showing an incorrect time of 18:45:02. the current time as I am writing this is 11.04.

Does anyone know what is wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Which dmbs? (dateadd and getdate are not ANSI SQL.)

Comment: i dont understand the qs

Comment: Sorry, I just asked which database product you are using. It's easier to get help if you tag your question with the database product you are using - especially if non-standard SQL is involved.

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied, did you check date and time on SQL Server instance maschine?

Comment: Thank you. Im using sql server express 2014 with advanced services

Comment: I did not check the time on the instance. How do i do that

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied, log on computer where SQL is installed and just check which date and time is set on computer

Comment: Run `SELECT GETDATE, DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE())` and check that what's returned matches what you expect.  You also use `GETUTCDATE` instead of `GETDATE` if you have a timezone issue.

Comment: the time thats displaying on my pc is 11:20:00  The time thats showing in DepTime column is 18:45:02. it should be 17:20:00

Comment: i tried running SELECT GETDATE, DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE()) and  i got error message saying" invalid column name Getdate"

Comment: Try `SELECT GETDATE(), DATEADD(hour, 6, GETDATE())` instead.

Comment: I ran what chsdk suggested and this returned                                  2015-02-20 11:29:34.327 2015-02-20 17:29:34.327.  These both appear to be correct but the columns in the table dont display these values.

Comment: thats what i want to display in the columns but the columns are not displaying the correct time or date

Comment: Make a little test: `DECLARE @t TABLE(d DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @t DEFAULT VALUES
SELECT * FROM @t`. If this returns correct values then obviously you are populating those columns with incorrect data. Notice that if you will provide insert clause with values to columns with defaults, provided value will be inserted not the default value on column

Comment: You stated in your question: `the current time as I am writing this is 11.04`.  The current time doesn't matter, what time was the row that you're looking at inserted into the table?

Comment: the time i created the DepTime default was 2015-02-19 13:03:51.687

Comment: You do realize that the datetimes stored in those columns will be the server datetime at the time of INSERT, correct?   And not at the time that you query or SELECT them, right?

Comment: I had presumed that because I used the Getdate() function they would auto update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the handling of defaults a bit counter-intuitive in SQL Server.  The syntax is:

```
DEFAULT constant_expression
```

It so happens that SQL Server *extends* the definition of `constant_expression` to include non-deterministic scalar functions, such as `getdate()`.  These are functions that return a different value each time they are called, even with the same arguments.  The definition in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) is:

> Only a constant value, such as a character string; a scalar function
>   (either a system, user-defined, or CLR function); or NULL can be used
>   as a default.

However, SQL Server does not extend the definition to *expressions* of such functions.  Instead, the expression is evaluated when the table is created and a constant value is inserted.

Unfortunately, one way to accomplish what you want is using a trigger.  Alternatively, you could leave the value as `NULL` and create a computed column to calculate the date six hours hence:

```
create table . . .
    _DepTime time,
    DepTime as (cast(dateadd(hour, 6 _DepTime) as time) )
```

Comment: i want the FlightDate column to be todays date. thats why i used getdate(). i could use the computed column though for the DepTime column

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied . . . It seems awkward to separate the time and the date into two columns.

Comment: can someone explain how the code below works.                                                                   create table . . .
    _FlightDate Date,
    FlightDate as (cast(dateadd(hour, 6 _FlightDate) as date) )

Comment: Gordon you might be right. I could just use the one column for flight date and time

Comment: if i did how would i set it that the time entered must be at least 6hrs from the current time. the reason is some airlines allow people to book and fly on the same day as long as their flight is 6hrs from the time of booking(current time)

Comment: I have deleted the FlightDate and DepTime columns and instead want to create a new column called Departure which will hold the Date and Time in one column. I need the date and time to be at least 6hrs from the current date and time.

I used part of statement which was provided by gordon Linof above but it is not working. Can someone suggest how to write this correctly.

Alter Table PriceTable
Add Column Departure AS (cast(dateadd(hour, 6 Depature) as Smalldatetime) )