# I need help writing a check constraint on a smalldatetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a Check constraint to a Column named Departure. This column has the smalldatetime data type.

The Check Constraint should state that:
The date and time entered in the Departure column must be at least 6 hours from whatever the current time is when the date is being entered.

Can anyone help with the code.

Thank you

Comment: DBMS? (Some products have limitations on how constraints can be added...)

Comment: Sql Server express 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName]
ADD CONSTRAINT DepartureLaterThan6Hours CHECK ([Departure] > dateadd(HOUR, 6, GetDate()));
```

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure though that the Getdate function will work as ive tried it in other functions and it enters a static date in the column. The date it enters is the same date the function was created.see the 2nd post in this link for an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627489/defaults-using-getdate-and-dateadd-are-not-working?noredirect=1#comment45561702_28627489

Comment: That's what GetDate() does, it gives you a snapshot value at the time of calling the function. It's not a dynamically updating reference to the system clock or anything that can be stored in a column. If you have a requirement for having a dynamically updated column, have a look at computed columns.